# Using RealmDB from WebService

Tags: asp.net, realm

Assumed I want to build an ToDo-list app for Android and iOS that uses RealmDB for storage and synchronisation. Would it be possible to use Realm in a ASP.NET based Web-Service as well to provide a webbased access to the ToDo-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm for .net [requires Xamarin](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/0.78.0/#prerequisites) and it only runs on iOS and Android, although there is a [popular issue requesting Windows support](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/721). It's not possible to use Realm in an ASP.NET application right now, but it's likely that this will be enabled soon.

Disclaimer: I work on Realm for Xamarin